# MySQL merge data on duplicate key

Tags: mysql, on-duplicate-key

I'm adopting dashboard now and I created two tables for selecting from frontend;

`DATA_SELECTED_HISTORY`
`DATA_SELECTED_NOW`

My frontend page get data from `DATA_SELECTED_NOW` and my backend algorithm put new data to this database.

I want to put my new data to `DATA_SELECTED_NOW`,
and the former data to be pushed to `DATA_SELECTED_HISTORY` when being faced with duplicate key.

I think I could use a swap table solution or insert(select subquery) + insert on duplicate key solution, but I don't get an idea anymore.

How can I use this solution in SQL?

Comment: Unclear... do you want each time when new row is inserted to move the most ancient row from this table to another table? If true then you cannot do this in query or by trigger, use stored procedure for this purposes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use trigger in this case, to check duplication before insert to DATA_SELECTED_NOW  and insert in DATA_SELECTED_HISTORY if it duplicates, check the below code

```html
CREATE TRIGGER TRIGGER_Name
BEFORE INSERT ON DATA_SELECTED_NOW
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  IF (EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM User WHERE key = NEW.Key)) THEN
  --  you can replace "key = NEW.Key " with your logic to check
   -- inset into DATA_SELECTED_HISTORY  
  END IF;
END$$
```